# Interpretation of a MANOVA

Tags: manova

I'm trying to do a MANOVA, checking the distribution to a dataset of multiple species to three different variables.
Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40196781/did-i-just-do-an-ancova-or-manova for original post.

I got a reply there, recommending using the mvabun package in R. 
- Did I do it correctly? 
- How should I interpretate this?

[image: Screenshot1]

[image: Screenshot2]